# Why use an extra let statement here?

Tags: swift

I'm looking at apple's iBook on the swift language and they use this snippet:

```
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

If I'm understanding correctly, this is just setting name to be the same as optionalName. Why then does Apple use `let name = optionalName`? Would it not be easier just to use `if optionalName {...`? From playing around it seems to have the behavior.

Comment: The gist: in short examples like that it makes little difference, but if you have a complex expression (see [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_312)) it's useful for binding a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if-let` construction is sort of superfluous in a simple case like this, but in a more complicated piece of code it can be useful. You can use it in a lot of the same ways you'd use an assignment in a conditional in (Obj)C (remember `if (self = [super init])`).

For example, if the optional being tested is a computed property:

```
var optionalName: String? {
get {
    if checkTouchID() {
        return "John Appleseed"
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
}
var greeting = "Hello!"
if optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(optionalName)"
}
```

Paste that into a playground, along with a stub implementation of `checkTouchID()` that returns `true`, and you'll immediately see in the results area that the `optionalName` getter is executing twice. If you use an `if-let` construction instead, you'll only execute the getter once.

This also true — and perhaps more commonly useful — if you have a series of chained optional calls, as in the `if let johnsStreet = john.residence?.address?.street` example from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_312). You don't want to rewrite the whole chain in the body of the `if` statement, much less recompute it.

Comment: What is if let name = optionalName {} checking? if optionalName is nil? Also why is the optionalName getter being executed twice?

Comment: The body of that `if` statement executes if and only if `optionalName` contains a value. Inside that statement, said value is bound to the local variable `name`. If `optionalName` has no value (i.e. "is `nil`"), control proceeds to the `else` clause (if one exists).

Comment: Why the quotes for "is `nil`"? It's important to note that `nil` is not a value in Swift. (In (Obj)C, `nil == (void *)0`.) It's just syntactic sugar indicating the absence of a value. This is important because it means you can't message `nil` (for better or for worse) or have code that breaks because you try to (or accidentally) dereference a pointer to a function or data at `nil`.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying `if-let` is simply a way of scoping. Without `let`, we have two calls to the `optionalName` getter. With `let` I can have one name set by calling `optionalName` and scoped down into the curly braces.

Comment: Why are there two calls of the optionalName getter without the let?

Comment: @Lucas because he says it twice, `if optionalName` ... `Hello, \(optionalName)`

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't use `if optionalName`.

> In an if statement, the conditional must be a Boolean expression—this
>   means that code such as if score { ... } is an error, not an implicit
>   comparison to zero.

It's mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1) in the `Guided Tour` of Swift.

Comment: Try it in a playground — you can indeed use an optional in an `if` statement to test for the presence of a value.

Comment: Well, you can indeed. This is weird.

Comment: Optional testing is the notable exception to "you can only use a `Bool` in a conditional". But there might be more: if you look at the definition of the `Optional<T>` type you'll see `func getLogicValue() → Bool` with the comment "Allow use in a Boolean context".