# Use of an optional value in Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

While reading the [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html), I came across this snippet:

> You can use **if** and **let** together to work with values that might be
>   missing. These values are represented as **optionals**. An optional value
>   either contains a value or contains nil to indicate that the value is
>   missing. Write a question mark (?) after the type of a value to mark
>   the value as optional.

```
// Snippet #1
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
optionalString == nil

// Snippet #2     
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

Snippet #1 is clear enough, but what is happening in the Snippet #2? Can someone break it down and explain? Is it just an alternative to using an `if - else` block? what is the exact role of `let` in this case?

I did read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift) page, but still a little confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if let name = optionalName {
   greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

This does two things:

1. it checks if `optionalName` has a value
2. if it does, it "unwraps" that value and assigns it to the String called `name` (which is only available inside of the conditional block).

Note that the type of `name` is `String` (not `String?`).

Without the `let` (i.e. with just `if optionalName`), it would still enter the block only if there is a value, but you'd have to manually/explicitly access the String as `optionalName!`.

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain the last line: you'd have to manually/explicitly access the String as optionalName!. A little ambiguous for me! Also, same block can be written as `if optionalName { greeting = "Hello, \(optionalName) " } right?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language?rq=1

Comment: Thanks! The answer with the link makes it much clear!

Comment: I don't think the last sentence is right. Using let doesn't make it optional binding. You can try `let stringNumber = "123;"
let numberOption = stringNumber.toInt();numberOption!`. numberOption is still an optional and you need to force unwrap it with '!'

Comment: @dalef: You don't have an `if` in there.

Comment: that's my point. should be without the if, not without the let. 'if name = optionalName {
   greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}' gives you compile time error of undeclared name instead

Comment: Well, you need both. The question (as I read it) was "why do I need the let, why can't I just use if alone".

Answer (score 4):

```
// this line declares the variable optionalName which as a String optional which can contain either nil or a string. 
//We have it store a string here
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"

//this sets a variable greeting to hello. It is implicity a String. It is not an optional so it can never be nil
var greeting = "Hello!"

//now lets split this into two lines to make it easier. the first just copies optionalName into name. name is now a String optional as well.
let name = optionalName

//now this line checks if name is nil or has a value. if it has a value it executes the if block. 
//You can only do this check on optionals. If you try using greeting in an if condition you will get an error
if  name{
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

Comment: So why can't `optionalName` be used directly. Why is it copied to `name` first?

Comment: It actually can be used directly. It doesn't really matter in this example but there are some advantages to not calling it directly every time. I actually had the same question myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004897/why-use-an-extra-let-statement-here

Comment: The reason for the `if let name = ...` idiom is that accessing the value of an optional variable when it's `nil` is a runtime error. Using this construction lets you write code that can't have that kind of error, since the block of the if statement doesn't get evaluated if `optionalName` is nil.

Answer (score 3):

`String?` is a boxed-type, variable `optionalName` either contains a `String` value or nothing(that is `nil`).

`if let name = optionalName` is an idiom, it unboxes the value out of `optionalName` and assign it to `name`. In the meanwhile, if the name is non-nil, the `if` branch is executed, otherwise the `else` branch is executed.

Comment: It's an algebraic type, not boxed.