# Swift Optionals

Tags: swift, option-type

Can someone please explain me the following code (appears on page 11 of Apple's Swift book):

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
optionalString = nil

var optionalName: String? = "Einav Sitton"
var greeting = "HELLO!"

if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030053/use-of-an-optional-value-in-swift/24030107#24030107

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swift requires types that can be optional to be explicitly declared, so the first snippet is an example of creating a nullable string:

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
optionalString = nil
```

In order to make use of a nullable string it needs to realized which it does with the `!` suffix so to convert a `String?` into a `String` you can do:

```
var name : String = optionalName!
```

But Swift also provides a shorthand of checking for and realizing a nullable inside a conditional block, e.g:

```
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
if optionalName != nil {
    let name = optionalName!
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about this line?

```
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

In english, this says: If `optionalName` has a value, set that value to the temporary variable `name` and then use it to construct a new string. If `optionalName` is `nil` do nothing at all.